# Create Markdown file from parsed Yaml

Tags: javascript, yaml, markdown, filesaver.js

I have a script that reads a csv file and from that I can create a file.
I am using YAMLJS (browser version, not node) to parse the generated json from the csv in to YAML.
How can I create a complete markdown file for it?
For example I have something like this:
`THUMB: thumb1.jpg;thumb2.jpg;` 
I want to output:

```
THUMB: 
- thumb1.jpg
- thumb2.jpg
```

Is that possible? The tools I use:
`papaparse`
`YAMLJS`
`FILESAVER`

Thanks

Comment: Yes, It is possible. If that is the format, you can just go through it line by line and replace some values. your delimiters being your `:` for your head and `;`  for your list items

Comment: Thanks, I am using `string.split(';')` and it returns me an array, then I pass the array to the YAML parser.